# Lotus domino Designer 8.5 File Upload Control reset

Tags: javascript, file-upload, lotus-notes

I'm supporting a Lotus Notes application that is running on an intranet on IE8. The Domino server is running version 8.5.x.

I am using a file upload control to attach a single PDF file to a record.

It works fine attaching the file and accessing it once the record has been saved, closed and re-opened.

What I would like to do is to be able to clear the file that has been selected PRIOR to the user submitting the form to be saved. The situation is that they might select a subsequent option on the form that invalidates the file attachment and I want the attachment to be automatically cleared.

**First attempt: Write to the value of the File Upload Control directly.**

I can access the value of the File Upload Control but it appears to be read-only, I cannot write to it directly.

```
alert('Filename: '+FileUploadControlName.value); // this works
FileUploadControlName.value = ""; // this doesn't work
```

Note, I get the name of the File Upload Control by calling a function called getName from the onFocus and onBlur events.

```
function getName(itm) {
    FileUploadControlName = itm;
}
```

"Other" attributes on the HTML tag of the File Upload Control:

```
onFocus="getName(this)" onBlur="getName(this)"
```

**Second attempt: Remove and re-add the File Upload Control**

I have got the following to work:

1. Wrap the file upload control in a division called attControlDiv.
2. Set the ID of the file upload control to attControl
3. Remove the file upload control element using the removeChild Javascript method.
4. Refresh the form to recreate the file upload control.

This is the code to remove and re-add the file upload control:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("attControlDiv");
var child = document.getElementById("attControl");
parent.removeChild(child);

_doClick('refresh', this, null, null);
```

Although this works, I want to avoid the form refresh and do it directly from within Javascript.

Is there any way to re-add the File Upload Control without triggering a form refresh?

Or is there another way to clear the value of the File Upload Control?

Edited to add a cut-down version of the html source:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="/XXX\XXX\YYY.nsf/Calendar.js?OpenPage"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="/XXX\XXX\YYY.nsf/Common.js?OpenPage"></SCRIPT>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/XXX\XXX\YYY.nsf/ActionBar.css?OpenPage"></style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/XXX\XXX\YYY.nsf/Common.css?OpenPage"></style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/XXX\XXX\YYY.nsf/WebTabs.css?OpenPage"></style>

<!-- code removed -->

</head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" onload="frm=document.forms[0]; ">

<!-- code removed -->

<form method="post" action="/XXX/XXX/XXX.nsf/XXX?OpenForm&amp;Seq=1" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="_XXX">

<!-- code removed -->

    <tr>
        <td class="LRTableLabel">
            Attach PDF</td>
        <td colspan="4" class="LRTableData"><div id="attControlDiv">
<input id="fileAttach" maxlength="12" type="file" name="%%File.ca2579e50002791d.e132be8c801a6853ca2575d6000ae341.$Body.0.9D60">    
<input type="button" onclick="$('#fileAttach').MultiFile('reset');" value="fileAttach Clear">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/XXX\XXX\YYY.nsf/jquery-1.8.0.min.js?OpenPage"></SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/XXX\XXX\YYY.nsf/jquery.MultiFile.js?OpenPage"></SCRIPT>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#fileAttach').MultiFile({
        max: 1,
        accept: 'pdf'
    });
});
</script>
        <!-- -->&nbsp;</div></td>
    </tr>

<!-- code removed -->

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Due to restrictions within the intranet that this application is running on where I cannot link to external webpages, I have downloaded the jquery and the multifile js code and implemented them as pages in a code database that is (successfully) used for all of the other code libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to achieve something similar using the JQuery Multifile plugin, found here : http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/

My Domino web application displays to the client a list of files that are pending upload when the form is submitted, and allows for removal of all or any of these files prior to submission.

This plugin will also allow you do restrict the number of attachments (in your case, 1) and the allowed file types (in your case .PDF only).

It's very simple to implement. Here is a suggestion of how it might work for you.

```
<form>
<div><input type="file" name="%%File.123123123123123.1231231231231231231231231.$Body.0.70" id="fileAttach" maxlength="12"></div>
<div>if below field equals 'clear', attachments will clear on field exit :</div> <div><input id="clearAttachments" type="text" /></div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.something.com/jquery.MultiFile.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#fileAttach').MultiFile({ 
        max: 1, 
        accept: 'pdf' 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
<script>
$('#clearAttachments').blur(function() {
    if ($('#clearAttachments').val() == "clear") {
        $('#fileAttach').MultiFile('reset')
    } 
});
</script>
```

I should add that I am in no way associated with the creators of this plugin - just a fan.

You can also try it here : http://jsfiddle.net/shwguhj6/

You will also need to at the ID to the file upload element, like this:

[image: file upload control ID]

Comment: Thanks for this Nick. This looks like it should work for what I need.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting it working, here's what I've done.

HTML Head Content: referenced jquery and multifile js

File upload control: ID: fileAttach

I've put the $(function(){ $('#fileAttach.... function you put in the example into the onLoad section. I wasn't sure if it should go here or just in the JS Header, I tried both but neither seems to work.

Not sure what else I need to do. The file upload just works like it did before, it seems that the multifile code is not being triggered. It doesn't react like the example in the jsfiddle.

What have I missed?

Comment: Hi Tim - make sure you add the ID to the file upload control (see above). Also, it will work fine if you add the "$(function(){ $('#fileAttach.... function" below the file upload control as passthru HTML on your form, and it's between <script> and </script> tags.

Comment: The form is a basic Notes form (content type = Notes) using pass-through HTML on the form where HTML is required. No error messages are appearing, but I'm not getting the filetype validation appearing (like it does in the jsfiddle), nor is anything different happening to the file upload control field once a file has been attached (in the jsfiddle it was greyed out and the filename was displayed). It is running on a Domino 8.5 server if that is significant.

Comment: our comments overlapped. I'll try what you've suggested and post an update. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The fileattach function is in the Head section of the form inside Script tags. This is the page source for the fileupload control and a button for clearing it: `<input id="fileAttach" maxlength="12" type="file" name="%%File.ca2579e50002791d.e132be8c801a6853ca2575d6000ae341.$Body.0.9D60"> <input type="button" onclick="$('#fileAttach').MultiFile('reset');" value="fileAttach Clear">`

Comment: try it beneath the file upload control as passthru HTML & not in the head section - you'll notice that in my example neither the declaration of the JS files or the functions are inside the head tags.

Comment: feel free to post the source HTML, i'm happy to check it out

Comment: OK, I placed the function directly under the file upload control and the button. Inside script tags and using passthrough html. Shows up in the View Source correctly. Doesn't work. Then I moved the library references to just above the function. Still doesn't work. Then I tried using jquery 1.8.0 instead of the latest 1.11.1 so that it matched the version you are using, and it still doesn't work!

Comment: Thanks for your offer re viewing the source html. I'm relatively new to SO, but I figure the comments section isn't the right place to post the source html. Where should I post it?

Comment: I've added the source html to the original question.

Comment: That works perfectly for me. Literally the only thing I changed in your code was the location of the jquery and multifile libraries. Try changing your jquery library to http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js and see if it works.

Otherwise you can put copies of the javascript libraries in the data/domino/html directory on your Lotus Domino Server, and reference them as http://servername/domino/html/file.name.js

Or you could put them in the 'Style Sheets' section of your notes application and reference them in your code like http://servername/filename.nsf/stylesheetname.css

Comment: OK, I've got it working! The issue was that pasting the js code into the pages doesn't work, I needed to add it as a file resource and reference it like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/XXX\XXX\YYY.nsf/jquery-1.8.0.min.js?OpenFileResource"></SCRIPT>`. I've moved the js reference into HTML Head Content, and the $function into JS Header and it all still works. Thanks again so much for all of your help.